# How to do things after an observable gets its data in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I am using an observable to retrieve data from an http like:

```
handleError(error:any) {
...
}
getData() {
   return this._api_service.http.get<JSON>(this._url).pipe(retry(1), catchError(this.handleError));
}
loadData() {
    this.getData().subscribe((data: {}) => {
        do_something_to_data(data);
    });
    // here I want to do somethings after all the data are loaded
    do_other_work();
    // what should I do here?
}
```

It seems do_other_work will get called before do_something_to_data is called. What should I change?

I tried next, pipe, but seems not working or observable does not support next().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that do_other_work() is called before do_something_to_data() is because Observable are asynchronous by nature.
To make sure that do_other_work() is called after the data is loaded and processed, you should call it inside the subscribe() method, after the do_something_to_data() call.

Placing do_other_work() inside the subscribe() method, will ensure that it is called after do_something_to_data() has been executed, and the data is fully loaded/processed.

```
loadData() {
    this.getData().subscribe((data: {}) => {
        // Pass the data to the do_something_to_data() function
        do_something_to_data(data);
        do_other_work();
    });
}
```

And like Austin said, You could also pass the data as an argument to do_something_to_data() function, assuming that the function accepts the data as an input parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, a subscribe is asynchronous, which means that the code inside the subscribe block is not executed immediately. Instead, it is placed in the event loop and will be executed after the current synchronous code has finished running.

Due to this asynchronous nature, any code written below the subscribe block may execute before the code inside the subscribe block. This is because the event loop prioritizes executing synchronous code before moving on to the queued asynchronous tasks.

Then you need put do_other_work inside of the subscribe.  Just like this:

```
loadData() {
   this.getData().subscribe((data: {}) => {
      do_something_to_data();
      do_other_work();
   })
}
```

Now, if what you want to do is ensure that do_other_work() is executed after do_something_to_data(), you can achieve this using a Promise.  Or you can do the following:

```
loadData() {
   this.getData().subscribe({
       next: (value) => {
           do_something_to_data();
       },
       error: (err) => {
          console.error('Error:', err);
       },
       complete: () => {
          do_other_work();
       },

   })
}
```

Comment: This is good I believe. what I am seeking is how to let the subscription fulfills its life cycle, then move onto do_other_work(). Is there such a step existing?

Comment: This is good too!

Comment: Oh ok, I just made an edit to the code I shared, check it out and let us know if it does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Do_other_work happens first, because it is called outside of the scope of the subscribe.

You can call

```
do_something_to_data(data);
```

Comment: I need to let do_something_to_data happen first since it has the data flow to it through the subscription. There should be one step after the subscription retrieve its data.

Comment: Then move the *do_other_work()" method inside the subscribe method